# with SQL, how to drop cases after a long gap in a time series?

Tags: sql, time-series, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

my data looks something like this:

|  | CASE_TIMESTAMP | GROUP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2017-12-26 16:12:09+00:00 | A |
| 1 | 2017-12-26 16:12:44+00:00 | A |
| 2 | 2020-04-21 07:00:00+00:00 | A |
| 3 | 2020-07-01 00:05:35+00:00 | A |
| 4 | 2020-08-06 07:00:00+00:00 | A |
| 5 | 2020-08-06 07:00:00+00:00 | A |
| 6 | 2020-08-06 07:00:00+00:00 | A |
| 7 | 2020-08-25 07:00:00+00:00 | B |
| 8 | 2020-09-22 07:00:00+00:00 | B |
| 9 | 2020-09-22 07:00:00+00:00 | B |
| 10 | 2020-12-04 08:00:00+00:00 | B |
| 11 | 2020-12-04 08:00:00+00:00 | B |
| 12 | 2020-12-07 08:00:00+00:00 | B |
| 13 | 2020-12-07 08:00:00+00:00 | B |
| 14 | 2020-12-07 08:00:00+00:00 | B |
| 15 | 2020-12-08 08:00:00+00:00 | B |
| 16 | 2020-12-08 08:00:00+00:00 | B |
| 17 | 2020-12-08 08:00:00+00:00 | B |

Need to drop cases that occurred before a gap of more than one day, so in group a all cases before 2020-08-06 and in B all cases before 2020-12-07.

Think I need a window function, but don't know how to calculate gaps and then drop all before, any ideas?

PS.I'm on snowflake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using QUALIFY and windowed MAX to find the latest CASE_TIMESTAMP per GRR:

```
CREATE TABLE t(CASE_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP,    GRP VARCHAR)
AS
          SELECT '2017-12-26 16:12:09+00:00','A'
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-12-26 16:12:44+00:00','A'
UNION ALL SELECT '2020-04-21 07:00:00+00:00','A'
UNION ALL SELECT '2020-07-01 00:05:35+00:00','A'
UNION ALL SELECT '2020-08-06 07:00:00+00:00','A'
UNION ALL SELECT '2020-08-06 07:00:00+00:00','A'
UNION ALL SELECT '2020-08-06 07:00:00+00:00','A'
UNION ALL SELECT '2020-08-25 07:00:00+00:00','B'
UNION ALL SELECT '2020-09-22 07:00:00+00:00','B'
UNION ALL SELECT '2020-09-22 07:00:00+00:00','B'
UNION ALL SELECT '2020-12-04 08:00:00+00:00','B'
UNION ALL SELECT '2020-12-04 08:00:00+00:00','B'
UNION ALL SELECT '2020-12-07 08:00:00+00:00','B'
UNION ALL SELECT '2020-12-07 08:00:00+00:00','B'
UNION ALL SELECT '2020-12-07 08:00:00+00:00','B'
UNION ALL SELECT '2020-12-08 08:00:00+00:00','B'
UNION ALL SELECT '2020-12-08 08:00:00+00:00','B'
UNION ALL SELECT '2020-12-08 08:00:00+00:00','B';
```

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
QUALIFY CASE_TIMESTAMP >= MAX(CASE_TIMESTAMP) OVER(PARTITION BY GRP) 
                          - INTERVAL '1 days';
```

Output:

[image]